# Image Hover Overlay with opaque text

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is create an image hover effect that when you hover over the image, the overlay is opaque and on it is normal text. Right now, the text and the background are opaque.

I've tried many things from z-index to changing the opacity on the text using CSS but nothing seems to fix it.

```css
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 425px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: -3.0;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://oi63.tinypic.com/141obo6.jpg" alt="dog" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>．：．Ａｐｐｅａｒａｎｃｅ．：．</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to post your overlay (and hover) css so we can see that too. That is where your issue likely is.

Comment: .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: -3.0;
    }

   container:hover .overlay {
   opacity: .5;
   }

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code instead? then format it as code

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the property `opacity`.
If you assign a opacity value to an element, then this will also apply to all the children inside that element, and in this case, your `.text` and `h3`.

You can get around this by using `rgba()` for the background-color of `.overlay` and adjust the opacity in there, so it will only apply to this element.

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wauLkbxp/29/).

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* background: #20262E; */
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 425px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -3.0;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.container:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://oi63.tinypic.com/141obo6.jpg" alt="dog" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>．：．Ａｐｐｅａｒａｎｃｅ．：．</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much! What did I do wrong? I notice you have a container for the hover .text so is that what I missed?